# TexStudio or any other such software: Is it possible to search for all labels with a specified number of references?

Tags: cross-referencing, texstudio, labels

This may be a stretch of the editor capabilities of TeXStudio and similar programs, but what I would like to do, as stated in the title, is to find all labels with a specified number of references. For instance, is there a way I can get TeXStudio to highlight (in a similar way as the -find- or -replace- commands work) all labels which have 0 references within the document? Or all labels which have 1 reference? etc.

My document is very large with many labels; this feature would help me a lot to edit it.

Comment: No idea. But t the log file show you if the  label is duplicated (multiply defined)  or a reference have no label (undefined (reference).   Moreover, there are packages to make a list (index) of labels, show in the margin, check if s label exist ... Take a tour of  https://ctan.org/topic/label-ref

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ with the [TeXiFy IDEA](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9473-texify-idea) plugin, you can use find references (Ctrl + b) on the label. This will show a list of all places where the label is used, with a total count of how often this label is used. There are inspections to check duplicate labels and labels that are not used, but I don't know of a general way to find all labels with a certain number of usages.